# How to position the floating label to right side of input of Angular Material UI

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, angular15

I want to position the floating label to the right side of input but I'm only able to position the label but gap is still there on the left.

Please help me position the both the gap and label to right side if any mat-form-field

I used dir="rtl" on body tag on index.html

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQi7J.png)